# In WinRT XAML App ListView.CanDragItems enables drag only in one direction when using touch

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

See the following very basic XAML. I run it in simulator in touch mode. I can drag the item right or left, but cannot down. It does work great when using mouse mode. After some googling I saw this thread (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/8bb5e423-4517-448b-89ce-179a978e9e2d/), but it did not help me out.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Background="AliceBlue" 
            AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" SelectionMode="None"  CanReorderItems="False"
                     IsItemClickEnabled="False" IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        Margin="10">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Blue" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <x:String>s1</x:String>
            <x:String>s2</x:String>
            <x:String>s3</x:String>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This is something so basic and it is strange that it does not work for me.
Does somebody know any solution or workaround?

Thanks

Meir

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but AFAIK using touch you can only tear off items perpendicular to the scrolling direction. The same has been mentioned in the forum post you're linking to. If you set `IsSwipeEnable=False` you disable this behavior as well.

If you want your `ListView` to scroll horizontally instead, since you've already changed the orientation of `ItemsPanelTemplate`, you need to add the following to your `ListView`:

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
```

Now tear off will work vertically instead of horizontally which should be more intuitive given your current layout.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about ScrollMode properties. I'm still interested to know whether the statement "can only tear off items perpendicular to the scrolling direction" is the final true and cannot be worked around. Actually, in my real layout I need to allow dragging diagonally.